# How to convert a glob pattern to a patsubst pattern in a gnu makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a pattern which I use with wildcard in order to find files. The pattern is specified in a variable as it is intended to be configurable (it's in an included makefile). I then need to use the same pattern with patsubst. Is there an easy way switch the `*` for a `%`? Obviously there could only be one `*` in the wildcard pattern.

So, for example, if my wildcard pattern is  `*.c` then I would like to obtain the pattern `%.c`

This would also need to work for the the following wildcard patterns:

```
WILD := *.c *.s *.S
WILD := prefix_*.suffix
```

I had a solution for the first case, where I am just working with extensions, which is to use patsubst itself:

```
PATSUBST_PATTERN := $(patsubst *.%,\%.%,$(WILD))
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this where the `*` is not at the start of the wildcard pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
WILD := *.c *.s *.S prefix_*.suffix
PATSUBST_PATTERN := $(subst *,%,$(WILD))
$(info $(PATSUBST_PATTERN))
```

Output:

```
%.c %.s %.S prefix_%.suffix
```

Comment: I'd completely overlooked the subst function. Now I feel stupid. Thank you for taking the time to answer, that works a treat.